# How to hide thead when tbody is empty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

The `if` in jinja2 is useful for know if a value is defined but I need to know if a query have results or not?
for example:

```
<thead>
{% if row in rows %} # this is a pseudo-code that i looking for
...
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for row in rows %}
...
</tbody>
```

rows is the result of a gql query where 'no result' is NULL but

```
{% if rows == NULL %}
```

or

```
{% if rows is none %}
```

don't help me. I want to hide thead when `tbody` is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried: `{% if rows %}`?

Edit:  To keep thead from showing up for each row, put the if statement outside of your for loop.  Something like:

```
{% if rows %}
<thead>
</thead>
{% endif %}

<tbody>
{% for row in rows %}
...
</tbody>
```

Comment: is ever true: rows is defined

Comment: If rows is empty this should equate to False, even if it is defined.

Comment: with rows empty:

    {% if rows %}
    {% for row in rows %}
    ..

thead is hidden but with 2+ add thead to any row :)

Comment: i'm sorry. After {% if rows %} I add thead. rows is false and thead isn't visible. when rows is true, for make visible thead only one time, what i need to add after {% if rows %} ?